# Optional permissions for "content scripts" in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

For a Google Chrome extension, I would like to have optional permissions for a "content script" so that the content script is activated only if the user has granted this optional permission. The extension's manifest has a `"content_scripts": [{..., "matches": "url"}]` that triggers a non-optional request for permission to read and change everything at that URL.

The [documentation on option permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions#manifest) does not mention content scripts. And the [documentation for RequestContentScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-RequestContentScript) still says it is not available in stable builds.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [RequestContentScript works on stable](https://crbug..com/409147), the devs just want to have freedom to change it *if* needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Firefox' [browser.contentScripts.register()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts/register) API and its [Chrome polyfill](https://github.com/bfred-it/content-scripts-register-polyfill) to register new content scripts dynamically. In Chrome 96+ there's also [chrome.scripting.registerContentScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-registerContentScripts), which does something similar.

You'll also have to watch for new permissions and register the scripts on the new hosts.

The module [webext-dynamic-content-scripts](https://github.com/bfred-it/webext-dynamic-content-scripts/#usage) takes care of all of this.